# Processor Utilization

Tags: processor, utilization

Out of curiosity ... is it possible to have more than 100% utilization of the CPU in a multi-threaded environment?

Answer (score 5):

No, of course not.  And any utility which tells you otherwise is lying.

Comment: @David, you need to keep your finger on the trigger a bit longerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr :-)

Answer (score 3):

a single CPU core can not be at more than 100% utilization. But on a multi core system most utilities report the sum of the CPU utilization thus numbers above 100% are quite common.

Comment: True. `top` can show more than 100% for a multithreaded application

Answer (score 0):

No, this could never happen by definition of cpu utilization.  What you may see is the number of runnable processes greater than the number of cpus.  This is normal in a multithreaded environment as the scheduler schedules on the thread level instaed of the process level.